# can't create a JsonObject java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object

Tags: java, json, gson

I have this code where "Ocupacion" is object class that have another atribute objects. (since is a large class i don't post all the atributes of the class)

```
public String genHor(){
    Collection<Ocupacion> ocupas = new ArrayList<>();
    ocupas= H.makeOcupacion();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(ocupas);
}
```

Then in another class where i recive the json String and i want to parse it. I do that:

```
public void assig(String json){
    JsonObject obj = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonObject();
}
```

Then i get the java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object

String json is like that:

```
[{"sesionConcreta":{"grup":{"NumGr":10,"TamGr":200,"subgrupo":[{"NumSub":11,"TamSub":200}],"asignatura":"prop"},"sessio":{"HorasSes":2,"TipoSes":"TEORIA"}},"aula":{"NomAu":"a5105","Capacidad":200,"Tipo":"lab"},"diayHora":{"Dia":"L","Hora":8}}]
```

Comment: As the exception states, this is not a valid json string, ints should be in quotes

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
[{"sesionConcreta":{"grup":{"NumGr":10,"TamGr":200,"subgrupo":[{"NumSub":11,"TamSub":200}],"asignatura":"prop"},"sessio":{"HorasSes":2,"TipoSes":"TEORIA"}},"aula":{"NomAu":"a5105","Capacidad":200,"Tipo":"lab"},"diayHora":{"Dia":"L","Hora":8}}]
```

it is a json array not a json object because it is in `[]` not in `{}`:

```
JsonArray jsonArr = new JsonParser().parse(json).getAsJsonArray();

JsonObject obj = jsonArr.get(0).getAsJsonObject();

JsonObject sesionConcretaObj = obj.get("sesionConcreta").getAsJsonObject();

JsonObject groupObj = sesionConcretaObj.get("grup").getAsJsonObject();

int numGr = groupObj.get("NumGr").getAsInt();
```

Comment: I already done that but then when i do that: int grup = obj.get("NumGr").getAsInt(); I get java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Naki2 because the `obj` that you get from this code has not the "NumGr" you have to get "SessionConcreta" object then from it get "group" object then from "group" object get the "NumGr" . i have updated my answer

Comment: @Naki2 it seems that you do not know much about JSON structure. but it is very simple to learn. it is similar to java array and java objects the `{}` sign surrounds objects and `[]` surrounds arrays & every object may have some properties

Answer (score 0):

The jsonString is actually a jsonArray not a jsonObject. Try with below:

```
String jsonStr = "[{\"sesionConcreta\":{\"grup\":{\"NumGr\":10,\"TamGr\":200,\"subgrupo\":[{\"NumSub\":11,\"TamSub\":200}],\"asignatura\":\"prop\"},\"sessio\":{\"HorasSes\":2,\"TipoSes\":\"TEORIA\"}},\"aula\":{\"NomAu\":\"a5105\",\"Capacidad\":200,\"Tipo\":\"lab\"},\"diayHora\":{\"Dia\":\"L\",\"Hora\":8}}]";

JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

for(int i = 0; i< jsonarray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject sesionConcreta = (JSONObject)jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).get("sesionConcreta");
  JSONObject grup = (JSONObject)sesionConcreta.get("grup");
  System.out.println(grup.get("NumGr"));
}
```

Comment: Please consider upvoting / accepting the answer if it did help, thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
public static void assig(String json){
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Ocupacion[] occs = gson.fromJson(json, Ocupacion[].class); 
        System.out.println(occs);
}
```